# How is cantrip damage determined when cast by NPCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, cantrips, npc, character-levels

A [Green Hag](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/green-hag) (MM, p. 177) has an Innate Spellcasting trait that includes the spell *vicious mockery*. The description of the [*vicious mockery*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vicious-mockery) cantrip states, in part:

> [The target] must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or take 1d4 psychic damage and have disadvantage on the next attack roll it makes before the end of its next turn.
>
> This spell's damage increases by 1d4 when you reach 5th level (2d4), 11th level (3d4), and 17th level (4d4).

How is cantrip damage determined when cast by NPCs?

I heard somewhere that the amount of hit dice in NPCs is used as their level. A green hag has 82 (11d8 + 33) hit points. So does *vicious mockery* do 3d4 psychic damage on a failed save when cast by a green hag?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Use Challenge Rating.

The introduction to the *Monster Manual* has a rule on page 10, under "Innate Spellcasting":

> [...] If a monster has a cantrip where its level matters and no level is given, use the monster’s challenge rating.

You can also read this section [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#InnateSpellcasting) in the *Basic Rules*.

So a Green Hag, which is CR 3, would deal 1d4 damage with *vicious mockery*.

Comment: I find this interesting... Why CR and not hit dice? Alas, I don't think there's a factual answer to that.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir The size of hit dice is tied to the size of a creature. So different sized creatures with similar hit points pools will have a wildly different number of hit dice. So it makes more sense for cantrip damage to be tied to the expected challenge of a creature than how big it is.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir there is also basically no consistency of number of hit dice within a given challenge rating.

Comment: Note that proficiency bonus on monsters is *also* tied to their CR, not their HD - monsters have a +2 if their CR is less than 5, +3 from 5 to less than 9, etc.  In general, the system treats CR as a proxy for character level for NPCs.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir: Are you are coming from a 3E background, where attack bonus and other factors were tied to Hit Dice, by any chance?...this is no longer the case in 5E.

Comment: Well, I'd expect a bard with 8d8+8 hit points to do 2d4 damage with Vicious Mockery, is all. This once again demonstrates how NPCs and PCs are different things, with different rules.

Answer (score 27):

#### Use the Green Hag's challenge rating as though it were her level

According to the rules on innate spellcasting (MM, p. 10):

> If a monster has a cantrip where its level matters and no level is given, use the monster's challenge rating.

Thus, a typical Green Hag (MM, p. 177) would do 1d4 damage with *Vicious Mockery*, because her challenge rating is 3. However, a Green Hag that is part of a coven would have a challenge rating of 5 (ibid), so it would do 2d4 damage with *Vicious Mockery* (as though the spell were cast by a 5th level character).